# Extract all occurrences of a single word before target

Tags: javascript, regex

In Javascript how can I extract all occurrences of a single word before a specific target?

Input:
"Abc FirstWord Target 123 other stuff SecondWord Target blah blah"

Output:
["FirstWord", "SecondWord"]

Thanks

Comment: Can u elaborate?

Comment: Is it always the same word before or you mean any word before the target?

Comment: Updated my answer (again)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The shortest form**:

> [.match(regex)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match): retrieves the matches when matching a string against a regular expression.

```js
var str = "Abc FirstWord Target 123 other stuff SecondWord Target blah blah";

var retVal = str.match(/([^\s])+(?=\sTarget)/g);


console.log(retVal);
```

**Splitting and reducing**:

- [split(regex)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)
- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
var str = "Abc FirstWord Target 123 other stuff SecondWord Target blah blah";
var retVal = str.split(/\W/).reduce(function(acc, ele, idx, arr) {
    if (ele == 'Target' && idx > 0) {
       acc.push(arr[idx - 1]);
    }
    return acc;
}, []);

console.log(retVal);
```

Comment: No, can be any word thsnks

Comment: @GaSacchi Answer updated. Now you have a short regex. Let me know. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

```js
var str = "Abc FirstWord Target 122 other stuff SecondWord Target";
var regex = /[a-z]*\sTarget/gi, result, els = [];
while ( (result = regex.exec(str)) ) {
    els.push(result[0].replace('Target', '').trim());
}
console.log(els);
```

Comment: Really like regular expression solution, it's simple to understand and works really well.

Answer (score 2):

### Pure regex answer

```js
let myString = "Abc FirstWord Target 122 other stuff SecondWord Target";
// match any word character before "Target", g(lobal) flag to get all the matches
let regex = new RegExp(/(\w*) Target/g);

let match = null;
let output = [];
// While we have results
while(match = regex.exec(myString)) {
  // Push the first capture group
  output.push(match[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Solution with ES6/Includes:

```
var myString = "Abc FirstWord Target 122 other stuff SecondWord";

var stringNew = myString.split(' ');
var output = [];

stringNew.forEach((i, index) => {
    console.log('item', index, i);
  if(i.includes('Word')) {
    output.push(i);
  }
});

console.log(output);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dm69txbc/

Check more info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes)

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. The OP wants the first word before `Target` not all the words which include the term `Word`

Comment: Yep, definitely =(

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [search()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search) with a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

```
    function getIndexesOfTermBeforeTarget(stringToSearch, term, target) {
      let foundIndexs = [];
      let isSearching = true;
      let regExp = new RegExp('.\*(?!' + target + ').\*' + term + '.\*');
      let lastFoundIndex;
      while(lastFoundIndex !== -1) {
        let lastFoundIndex = stringToSearch.slice(lastFoundIndex).search(regExp);
        if(lastFoundIndex !== -1)(
          foundIndexs.push(index);
        }
      }
      return foundIndexes
    }
```

This matches any term that is not preceded by the target. If the target must follow the match, use `'.*(?!' + target + ').*' + term + '.*(?' + target +')*'`